# How to highlight code in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to display code (javascript, ruby etc) in Drupal like this page:

http://vowsjs.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at these:

- [How to display code in drupal](http://www.thisblog.runsfreesoftware.com/?q=2009/03/09/how-display-code-drupal)
- [GeSHi Filter module](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter)

Here is active link for GeSHi:

- [GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)